# run 2 jobs with same jenkinsfile and different parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to configure 2 jobs in Jenkins that use the same jenkinsfile but the only difference is the parameters to these jobs.

for example: 
create 2 jobs named: A and B  that each one of them gets param of X.
in A the job get X as 1 and in B the X is 2.

I want to create it in this way instead of one job that has multi-checkbox because the jobs are independent and I don't want to leave any option to make mistakes.

How can I achieve that only via jenkinsfile? 
I read about load jenkinsfile within other jenkinsfile but can't find a way to pass parameters.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How is the job  being triggered? Did you check parameterized job?

Comment: the jobs triggered via Jenkins "build with parameters". I need to create 2 jobs using the same Jenkins file but different parameters

Answer (score 0):

my solution was:

in Jenkins file to set

```
environment {
             X= getX(env.JOB_NAME)
             Y= getY(env.JOB_NAME)  

     }
```

and create the following functions in the end of pipeline:

```
def getX(jobName)
{
  if (jobName.contains("X1"))
  {
    return "X1";
  }
  else return "X2";
}

def getY(jobName)
{
    if (jobName.contains("BLA"))
    {
      return "BLA1";
    }

  return "BLA2";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use `Build with Parameters` you can reference these declared parameters in the Jenkinsfile with this syntax `${PARAM}`.

You could also declare a `Choice Parameter` named `CHOICE` in a declaritive pipeline it would look like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
     choice(name: 'CHOICE', choices: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], description: 'Pick something')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo "Choice: ${params.CHOICE}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would not need 2 jobs this way. It is the same job but it runs with different configurations for `CHOICE`.

This example is directly taken from the official docs: 
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Comment: as I said : "I want to configure 2 jobs